# How to incorporate gulp-uncss with yeoman generator gulp-webapp

Tags: gulp, yeoman-generator, gulp-uncss

I included gulp-uncss:

```
var uncss = require('gulp-uncss');
```

Then I added its function to the `styles` task:

```
gulp.task('styles', () => {
return gulp.src('app/styles/*.scss')
.pipe($.plumber())
.pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
.pipe($.sass.sync({
  outputStyle: 'expanded',
  precision: 10,
  includePaths: ['.']
}).on('error', $.sass.logError))
.pipe($.autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 1 version']}))
.pipe($.sourcemaps.write())
.pipe(uncss({
        html: ['dist/index.html']
    }))
.pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/styles'))
.pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});
```

But, it's not working because the `index.html` hasn't been generated yet.

Given yeoman generator gulp-webapp's gulpfile, how is it possible to make uncss process the `main.css` file upon build?

Comment: I tried adding `  .pipe(uncss({
      html: ['src/**/*.html']
    }))` to line 55 of styles.js but it stripped most of my styles away

Comment: also tried `.pipe(uncss({html:'src/app/**/*.html'}))` at build.js:54 (which is ostensibly the correct place for it) and it stripped all my styles